# How to pass Page as ref parameter to a function

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to know how Can I paas Page as Ref Parameter to a function

This is what I want to do

```
 
  public partial class HomePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!SetupUserPermission.isSessionExpired())
        {
            string UserId = Session["UserId"].ToString();
            SetupUserPermission.SetupUserRights(ref this.Page, Convert.ToInt32(UserId));
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't pass a property by reference in C#. Why do you want to pass Page by reference in this case?

In VB you *can* pass a property by reference, and the equivalent in this case would be:

```
Page tmp = Page;
SetupUserPermission.SetupUserRights(ref tmp, Convert.ToInt32(UserId));
Page = tmp;
```

Are you really sure you want to do that?

I suspect you don't really want to pass it by reference, and you're just slightly confused about parameter passing. See [my article on the topic](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html) for more information.

Comment: d'oh! just as I add the same link in ;-p

Comment: I'm not going to object to two links to the same article :)

Answer (score 3):

Why do you want to pass it `ref`? It seems to me that a regular pass should do; this passes the **reference** by value - which is what you want (unless you are creating a new page...).

Also, isn't "`this`" the `Page`? Can't you just:

```
SetupUserPermission.SetupUserRights(this, ...);
```

where `SetupUserRights` takes a `Page`?

See also: Jon Skeet's page on [parameter passing in C#](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html); that might fix a few misconceptions (hint: `Page` is a *reference-type* (a class)).

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need to alter the reference of this.Page in downstream calls and have the reference reflect the changes upstream, there is no reason to pass this by ref.  Either way i don't think this works with properties, especially get only ones like this.Page.